# StartActivityForResult from a bounded Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a Service that is bounded to an Activity A, from this Service I need to call an Activity B and wait for the result.

I manage to call the activity B like that:

```
val intent = Intent(contextOfActivityA, ActivityB::class.java)
(contextOfActivityA as ComponentActivity).startActivityForResult(intent, 123)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to catch the result of the ActivityB.
If I use onActivityResult is never called:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //result
    }
```

How can I do that? Bear in mind that I can control only the Service so I can't modify or handle the result call in the Activity A.

Thanks

Comment: "from this Service I need to call an Activity B and wait for the result" -- that is truly frightening from an Android app architecture standpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain why?

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to do this and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I've changed the app infrastructure in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. `Service`s run as stand-alone entities, have no UI and perform background activities. When a `Service` launches an `Activity`, the `Activity` runs in a task associated with UI. An `Activity` can launch another `Activity` and get a result back (using `startActivityForResult()`), but a `Service` is a whole different thing.

Comment: I understand now that the service can be the wrong architectural choice since I have to work with UI too, do you have in mind what's the most correct one?

Comment: You can provide persistency by writing data to an SQLite database, or to files or store date in `SharedPreferences`. Not exactly sure what you are trying to build here.

Comment: I've changed the app infrastructure in the end.